# Only match the href="http inside the reges

Tags: php, regex

I'm using the following regex to select the `href="http` part inside an url which doesn't contain a `rel="nofollow"` yet:

```
preg_replace(
    "/<a\b(?=[^>]+\b(href=\"http))(?![^>]+\brel=\"nofollow\")/', 
    "rel=\"nofollow\" href=\"http://", 
    $input_string
);
```

The thing is it only replaces the `<a` because that's the first match.

How is it possible to select the a tag but exclude the `<a` part from the results so it only will match `href="http`? Because `preg_match` does return `<a` AND `href="http`, but I only need `href="http` :)

The reason I think this might be the only right solution is because it's not sure how many `<a>` tag the given string contains and whether they contain a `rel=nofollow` or not. I need to make sure I only replace the `http://` with `rel="nofollow" http://` inside `<a>` tags with no `rel="nofollow"`

**EDIT 1:**

giuseppe straziota asked for an input and output example so here it is:

input:

```
this is a string with a lot of content and <a href="http://information.nl" class="aClass">links</a> and whatever....
```

output:

```
this is a string with a lot of content and <a rel="nofollow" href="http://information.nl" class="aClass">links</a> and whatever....
```

**EDIT 2:**

I run a couple of more tests, these are the results:

code (exact copy/paste):

```
$input_string = 'this is a string with a lot of content and <a href="http://information.nl" class="aClass">links</a> and whatever....';

$input_string = preg_replace(
    '/<a\b(?=[^>]+\b(href="http))(?![^>]+\brel="nofollow")/', 
    'rel="nofollow" href="http://', 
    $input_string
);

echo htmlentities($input_string);
```

result from php 7.0.5:

```
this is a string with a lot of content and rel="nofollow" href="http:// href="http://information.nl" class="aClass">links</a> and whatever....
```

And it should be:

```
this is a string with a lot of content and <a rel="nofollow" href="http://information.nl" class="aClass">links</a> and whatever....
```

**EDIT 3:**

I tried this regex:

```
$test = preg_replace(
    '/(?=<a\b[^>]+\b(href="http))(?![^>]+\brel="nofollow")/', 
    'rel="nofollow" href="http://', 
    $input_string
);
```

But now it places the `'rel="nofollow" href="http://'`, right before the `<a`, so the result:

```
rel="nofollow" href="http://<a href="http://information.nl" class="aClass">links</a>
```

Not exactly what I want either...

Comment: Can you insert an example of input and output, please?

Comment: I've added an example of input and output ;)

Comment: I hope to have undestood the problem, here you'll find my test https://regex101.com/r/bI2qQ0/1 work with more <a> tags in the string

Comment: What a problem, your expresion works as you want - https://regex101.com/r/bI2qQ0/2

Comment: @splash58 I'm running some more tests, because regex101 returned different results than phpfiddle and phpliveregex.com before I asked this question, so I'm running a couple more tests right now.

Comment: Maybe, you show samples did not pass the test ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking too difficult, I made some adaptions in my preg_replace so I can just use the first regex:

```
$test = preg_replace(
    '/<a(?=\b[^>]+\b(href="http))(?![^>]+\brel="nofollow")/', 
    '<a rel="nofollow"', 
    $input_string
);
```

It replaces the `<a` tag, so I should have taken advantage of that like I do now.